# escaping \n in \s match in reg ex python

Tags: python, regex

I want to substitute all space characters (except `\n`) with `""`. I tried using regular expression with `\s+` but it matches with newline character as well.

Is there any method to skip `\n` in `\s` in regex?

Comment: I dont think so... Escape separately `[\t ]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you do not have to think of Unicode, you could use

```
[ \t\r\f\v]
```

Or, since `\v` matches a VT (verical symbol, `\x0b`), `\r` is also considered a line break, and `\f` is also a kind of a vertical whitespace (rather obsolete now though - (form feed, `\x0c`):

```
[ \t]
```

See [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

> `\s`
>   When the `UNICODE` flag is not specified, it matches any whitespace character,  this is equivalent to the set `[ \t\n\r\f\v]`. The `LOCALE` flag has no extra effect on matching of the space. If `UNICODE` is set, this will match the characters `[ \t\n\r\f\v]` *plus* whatever is classified as space in the Unicode character properties database.

If you need to support all Unicode spaces, use

```
\s(?<!\n)
```

This expression will match any whitespace that is not a line feed.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sE4cX2/1)

Another example of how to add a restriction to a *positive* shorthand character class, is using its opposite inside a negated character class. `\S` is the opposite shorthand character class for `\s`, thus, we should put it into `[^...]` and *add the character from `\s` that we need to exclude:

```
[^\S\n]
```

Add `\r`, `\v`, etc. if you need to exclude all line breaks. The `[^\S\n]` matches any character other than a non-whitespace (=matches any whitespace) and a line feed character.

Comment: "Or, since `\v` may also match a linefeed...": Not in Python it can't.

Comment: @AlanMoore: The `\v` is present on the whitespace list. It denotes a vertical space. Thus, I suggest removing it if all possible newline symbols are to be excluded. `print(hex(ord("\v")))` [prints](https://ideone.com/a7Ss9Y) `0xb` (`= vertical tabulation (VT)`)

Comment: I agree the OP should be excluding all vertical whitespace (which includes `\f`, BTW).  But you said `\v` matches a linefeed, and that's not true.  `\v` matches a vertical tab, and `\n` matches a linefeed.

Comment: But while substituting it is not working on multi space. How to fix that. e.g sst= "\nnew some  text \t heretab\t see     \n frw\n sdf\n"                                  I want output like this "\nnew some text heretab see \n frw\n sdf\n"

Comment: It should work with `output = re.sub(r'[^\S\n]', '', input)`

Comment: I see you want regular spaces in the output - then add a space to the character class like `output = re.sub(r'[^\S\n ]', '', input) `

Comment: I am on a mobile and cannot check properly.:-(

Comment: Hey Wiktor, I tried this one "(\s(?<!\n))+" . It is working. But is it safe to use. I dont understand this pattern that is why I am asking.

Comment: Hey re.sub(r'([^\S\n])+', ' ', sst) this is working. Thanks :)

Comment: Aha, so, you want to replace subsequent multiple whitespace symbols. What do you mean by safe? The regex is correct syntactically, and if it does what you need it is safe for you to use. It just matches one or more whitespace that is not a line feed.

Comment: You do not need a capturing group with the pattern you commented on last: `re.sub(r'[^\S\n]+', ' ', sst)`  is enough.

Answer (score 2):

It's [said in the document that `\s` matches `[ \t\n\r\f\v]`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). So you just need to replace  '\s+' to **[ \t\r\f\v]+** in order to skip \n.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the negated character class `[^\S\n]` where `\S` is all that is not a whitespace:

```
re.sub(r'[^\S\n]', '', s)
```

Comment: I have come back to add this to my answer and see this. I will still add it.

Answer (score 0):

`\s` matches `[\r\n\t\f ]`, if you want only spaces you can use the following:

```
>>> re.sub(' ', '', 'test   string\nwith  new line')
```

Since `' '` matches a space (literally), this will remove all spaces but will keep the `\n` character.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any method to skip `\n` in `\s` in regex?

You may use negative lookahead.

```
re.sub(r'(?!\n)\s', '', s)
```

If you also want to skip carriage return then add `\r` inside the negative lookahead.

```
re.sub(r'(?!\n|\r)\s', '', s)
```

It's like a kind of subtraction. ie, above regex would subtract `\n`, `\r` from `\s`

Comment: Hey Thanks Avinash. In some places it is not working.

Comment: Example:- mystrng = ""\na dsf cd\n b\n c  hdfbs   \n  dffs \t fdvfv\tdfd dsf\n":        For this string it is removing the "\n" in between hdfbs and dffs. Can you please tell me how to fix this one.